# How to write javascript to div that self executes

Tags: javascript

My application is retrieving content from an XML file that has javascript in it. I am taking the javascript and placing it into my DOM, but the script is not executing.

How do I write javascript onto my page that will then execute?

My app goes something like this...

```
var javaScriptFromFile = getJS();
myDiv.innerHTML = javaScriptFromFile;
//Next, how do I execute the javascript? 
//Can I make the javascript in the innerHTML self executing?
```

Comment: First start by *not* doing that, and instead load the script content as a script file.

Answer (score 1):

You could [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) the javascript. Or wrap in `<script>` tags before putting in the `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 1):

put it in a script tag insted of a div. but are you sure this is ***really*** what you want?

Comment: Putting a script tag does not cause it to execute. If javaScriptFromFile is "<script>alert('test');</script>" nothing happens.

Comment: did you append the script tag to the dom?